# join table horizontally by loop based on rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have a dataframe `data_df` with `n` rows:

```
Rank       DutyCode
200        ABC
300        DEF
400        GHI
```

Then, I want to iteratively join them as one row, example:

```
Rank       DutyCode  Rank_1      DutyCode_1    Rank_2       DutyCode_2 
200        ABC        300        DEF           400        GHI
```

My current code :

```
column_data_df = data_df.iloc[[1]]
data_df.iloc = data_df.iloc.drop([0])

data_df = data_df.join(column_data_df, rsuffix='_1')
```

and only produce :

```
Rank       DutyCode  Rank_1      DutyCode_1    
200        ABC        300        DEF
```

This only works for one time.. I want it to be dynamic for `n` number of rows.

**EDIT**

Another dataframe :

```
       Rank             DutyCode
{'a':'b', 'i':'j'}        ABC
{'a':'b', 'i':'j'}        DEF
{'a':'b', 'i':'j'}        GHI
```

To :

```
Rank.a  Rank.i  DutyCode  Rank_1.a  Rank_1.i   DutyCode_1
   b       j       ABC       b        j           DEF
```

I hope this makes sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` with `MultiIndex`, convert to one row `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose and last flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.stack().to_frame().T
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}').str.replace('_0','')
print (df)
  Rank DutyCode Rank_1 DutyCode_1 Rank_2 DutyCode_2
0  200      ABC    300        DEF    400        GHI
```

Or for flatten use list comprehension:

```
df = df.stack().to_frame().T
df.columns = [f'{b}' if a == 0 else f'{b}_{a}' for a, b in df.columns]

print (df)
  Rank DutyCode Rank_1 DutyCode_1 Rank_2 DutyCode_2
0  200      ABC    300        DEF    400        GHI
```

EDIT:

```
import ast

#if necessary
#df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df = pd.json_normalize(df.pop('Rank')).add_prefix('Rank.').join(df)
print (df)
  Rank.a Rank.i DutyCode
0      b      j      ABC
1      b      j      DEF
2      b      j      GHI

df = df.stack().to_frame().T
df.columns = [f'{b}' if a == 0 else f'{b}_{a}' for a, b in df.columns]

print (df)
  Rank.a Rank.i DutyCode Rank.a_1 Rank.i_1 DutyCode_1 Rank.a_2 Rank.i_2  \
0      b      j      ABC        b        j        DEF        b        j   

  DutyCode_2  
0        GHI
```

Comment: Any other way to avoid lambda?

Comment: @cna - Sure, added another solution

Comment: hey wondering how this code can be improvised to also unpack column with dictionary. I can provide example..

Comment: @cna - OK, super, waiting for example

Comment: Great!, will do now

Comment: Getting `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'` at `json.normalize`

Comment: Ah I think its because there are Nan rows

Comment: Ok got it, `dropna()` solved the issue. Thank you very very very much :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the cleanest way, but it works:

```
import pandas as pd
input = pd.DataFrame(data=[[200, 'ABC'], [300, 'DEF'],[400, 'GHI']],\
             columns=['Rank' ,'DutyCode'])

df = input.iloc[0]
for row in range(1,len(df)+1):
    df['Rank_' +str(row)] = input.loc[row]['Rank']
    df['DutyCode_' +str(row)] = input.loc[row]['DutyCode']
```

Comment: This is more intuitive. Thanks!

Comment: I think loop in pandas is antipattern, so you can avoid it. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758).

Comment: @jezrael : thank you for the tip. I knew it's not pythonic (pandastic), for me it's just easier to understand - nevertheless good to know - if performance is needed.